# I can't connect my ASP .NET app from Docker-container to my computer host database with "host.docker.internal:some-port"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker, model-view-controller, azure-cosmosdb

I lost amount of time trying to connect my app container with my database Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. I am using loggers object to know where my app break, and I found that the problem is in the connection of the container out of him. I tried to use the famous host.docker.internal direction to connect my host but using my container name (the public IP and DNS internal server of docker).

Here is my appsettings.Development configuration:

```
  "DocumentDb": {
    "TenantKey": "Default",
    "Endpoint": "https://project-cosmos-container:8081",
    "AuthorizationKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
  },
```

Here my Dokerfile-Cosmos (here I copy my app .ddl that I created before with dotnet build and dotnet publish):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
# We create the folder inside the container
WORKDIR /local-project

# We are coping all project executables that we created with dotnet build and dotnet publish 
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/* ./

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8081

# We indicate to execute the program in the executable of the project
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Local.Proyect.Core.dll"]
```

And finnally my docker-compose where I run the app:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    local-Proyect:
      image: project-cosmos-image
      container_name: project-cosmos-container 
      ports:        
        - 127.0.0.1:7000:8000        
      environment:
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:8000
```

Maybe the problem is in the ports, I don't Know. You can see that I am trying use my port 7000 on my computer host to connect the container and the port 8081 (**azure cosmos port**)

Comment: Shouldn't `https://project-cosmos-container:8081` point to your localhost - or at least the loopback address (127.0.0.1))?

Comment: I did it and the app broke with a error: "EROR: for project-cosmos-container  Cannot start service local-Proyect: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint project-cosmos-container (81f82343317f2ceed35569622dc9ad2c3f3f477dcd0041bd62a1ce5798348d00): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 127.0.0.1:8081: unexpected error Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsing the following configuration with `host.docker.internal:8081`it works.

```
"DocumentDb": {
    "TenantKey": "Default",
    "Endpoint": "https://host.docker.internal:8081",
    "AuthorizationKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
  },
```

So using the container name like DNS direction not works. I also have to do in Develpment environment because in other diferent `host.docker.internal` not works...

```
version: '3.1'
services:
   local-Proyect:
      image: project-cosmos-image
      container_name: project-cosmos-container 
      ports:        
        - 127.0.0.1:7000:433
        - 127.0.0.1:7001:80
      environment:
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:433;http://+:80
```